# Как сделать бесконечные иттерации

Tags: python

Как заставить питон в этом коде продолжать иттерации

```
a=[1,2]
a.append(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: здесь нет ни одной итерации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[1,2]
while True:
    a.append(a)
    print(a)
```

Итерация - это 1 шаг внутри цикла. Здесь будет бесконечные итерации.

Comment: Я имел ввиду как избежать того, что питон пишет[1,2,[...]] и без использования списка. Питон понимает, что я собираюсь сделать.

Comment: вывод [1, 2, ...] - это рез-тат работы **print(a)**. Если не хотите его вывод, то сотрите.

Comment: Благодарю, а можно все-таки это как-то вывеси без использования цикла. А в Python 2 - это будет работать?

Comment: Циклы созданы для того, чтобы не повторять одно и то же действие. Во 2ой тоже будет работать.

Comment: Да, проверил уже на python 2. Извиняюсь но у меня еще один вопрос. Используя ваш код  с циклом, у меня так же создаются троеточия, как я понимаю чтобы не нагружать ПК. Это можно как-то обойти?

Comment: Многоточия - это потому что на каждой итерации Вы добавляете список в список